# If $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$ and $P(|X|>c)$ is known, what do we know about $P(|X_n|>c)$?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

By definition if random variables $X_n$ converge in probability to some $X$ we have $$P(|X_n-X|>\varepsilon)\rightarrow 0$$for any $\varepsilon>0$. Can any information be deducted on the quantity $P(|X_n|>c)$ if $P(|X|>c)$ for some $c\in \mathbb{R}$ is known?

Comment: It would seem like a good guess that $P(\lvert X_n \rvert > c) \to P(\lvert X \rvert >c)$. However, there may be subtleties involved here, try to work them out.

Comment: That's what I also guessed but I was not able to prove it. By the triangle inequality we have $|X_n-X|\leq |X_n|-|X|$, therefore $2c<|X_n-X|$ implies $2c<|X_n|+|X|$ which implies that $c < |X_n|$ or $c < |X|$ which gives by monotonicity $0\leftarrow P(|X_n-X|>2c)\leq P(|X_n|>c) + P(|X|>c)$ which makes it bigger and not smaller.

Comment: See Sangchu Lee's comment for the subtleties. That would give you the complete answer, combined with ayeayemaung's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed Answer**

As shown by @SangchulLee in the comments, there are examples of degenerate random variables where, say for some $c > 0$, you let $X_n = c + 2^{-n}$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ and let $X = c$. Then $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$ and you even know $P[|X| > c] = P[|c| > c] = 0$. But $P[|X_n| > c] = P[|c + 2^{-n}| > c] = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. So knowing $P[|X| > c]$ has no advantage to knowing $P[|X_n| > c]$ however large $n$ is.

But assuming $\pm c \in \mathbb R$ are points of continuity of the cdf of $X$, you can say the following:

Note: convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution i.e. for each $x \in \mathbb R$ **such that $x$ is a point of continuity of $X$**, we have $P[X_n \leq x] \to P[X \leq x]$. So in this case $P[|X_n| > c] \to P[|X| > c]$ too.

Comment: You are misunderstanding convergence in distribution. The convergence of probability is guaranteed to hold only when $\pm c$ are continuity points of the CDF of $X$. As an example, consider the case of degenerate RVs $X_n = c+2^{-n}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks, realized I was missing something subtle after the fact; I will try to salvage the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$P[|X_n| > c] = P[|X_n| > c, |X| > c - \epsilon] + P[|X_n| > c, |X| \le c - \epsilon]$$